# Setting store to admin results in empty collection

Tags: admin, product-collection

I'm writing a frontend editor that requires changing the 'All Store Views' attributes for products. (As well as being able to change per store).

I can flick between frontend stores without problem and it shows the correct values, but if I set it to the admin store, then the collection (which contains products for any other store) is suddenly empty.

This is the code I am using:

```
    $filters = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('store')){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($this->getRequest()->getParam('store'));
    }else{
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
        Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
    }


    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addCategoryIds()
                ->addUrlRewrite()
                ->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents();


    $products->load();
```

Using the above, if I pass it a store of 1 or 2, then it works and the products are available in the collection. If I don't pass a store, (which should automatically set it to the admin store), or I pass it a store of 0, then the collection is empty

Can anyone advise on why this is, and what I can do to get the 'default' values for editing?

Thanks!

Comment: Magento Display product at front end by checking 2 things, Website assigned to product and Visibility.
In Above code what you are doing is normal, If you passed 1 and 2 then the function display product which visibility is set to "catalog, catalog and search". If you set 0 then, It display empty collection because 0 is admin store id. you can't load products with store id 0

Comment: Hi Charlie, okay,  but there must be some way of default entity values? Magento gets them in the backend, so it can't be impossible?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addStoreFilter($currentWebsiteId);
```